# Custom widgets (buttons, boxes, etc) for android

Tags: android, android-widget, custom-widgets

What are the possibilities to develop android apps with custom styled widgets (by widgets I mean gui elements like buttons, boxes, menus). I want to develop android apps which don't use the standard look and feel of android. What are the widget libraries available? Are there any other ways to achieve this?

One of the possibilities would be to use html and phonegap and style the app with css. But I'm looking for a non-html and phonegapesque way to achieve this.

Look for example at the apps mentioned on the following page:

http://androidquark.com/top-6-best-alternative-photography-apps-instagram/

did they draw their widgets themselves? Or can such effect be achieved using the themeing mentioned in one of the answers?

Comment: I am not an android expert, but I think you should be able to do what you want by subclassing `android.view.View`, just like in all other GUI toolkits.

Comment: Then it is necessary to draw the widgets yourself. I'm looking for more high-level solutions for this problem.

Comment: Maybe something like : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your widgets just about any way you wish.  For example, buttons are easy to customize by using ImageButton, and assigning it to any graphic you wish.  Here's an example of custom "buttons" in a palette in a soon to be released update to an app of mine...even the crayons are buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find a collection of them here:
https://github.com/mingyuan-xia/DevAndroidQuickly